# CMD Adding a New Text Line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, newline

Okay so I basically need a code that will do something like this:

```
@echo off
start:
echo Type what you want me to remember!
set /p newline=
<add %newline% to Line 4 in safe.txt>
goto start
```

I don't want to replace the existing Line 4 in `safe.txt`.

Comment: echo %newline%>>safe.txt

Comment: Do you need to append `%newline%` to the end of `safe.txt` or do you need to add it to the fourth line in `safe.txt` regardless of how many lines are in the file?

Comment: An example would have been good. Do you mean to simply append the new input as a new line (at the end of the file) or as a new line (after line 4 of the file) or (by appending it to the existing line 4 of the file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the input to the end of the file:

```
@echo off
start:
echo Type what you want me to remember!
set /p newline=
Echo %newline% >> safe.txt
goto start
```

If you want to add the line **after the 4th line**:

```
@echo off
start:
echo Type what you want me to remember!
set /p newline=

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
ren safe.txt safe.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (safe.tmp) do (
set /a count+=1
Echo %%a >> safe.txt
if !count!==4 Echo !newline! >> safe.txt
)
del safe.tmp
goto start
```

And one of these codes should help you with your problem.

Mona